# A conversation about logic gates

Tags: computer-puzzle, steganography

You are in a room with four buttons and a piece of paper.

There is a weird dialogue about logic gates on the paper.

> Hello, *my favorite logic gates are* AND and NAND
>
> . *I said* Hello And *he said* Hi Hi *and he asked me if I liked the AND gate and I replied* Yes
>
> *then he said:* so Come Get The AND g
>
> ate *and then I went to his house and I* Got The Gate *and then his friend came and said* Hi *and I said* H
>
> ello *and then I asked what are these logic gates you're holding and he replied* Oh *they are* AND and AND *gates*.

The buttons have labels:

```
- JvKq1t65K0

- DHI3A3jZ3R

- VX9g4S15f6

- gVLYHV8D29
```

Only one of the buttons opens the exit door. Which is the correct one?

**Hint 1:**

> A fixed width font may help.

**Hint 2:**

> You have to remove some things to get the right message.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Nice puzzle. Your hint does suggest that a format-edit of your original quesion might be a good idea. Have you considered that? (The hint refers to the button labels?) You could simply use "code formatting" for example.

Comment: I thought about putting the text in a code block, but that would make the italic text look a bit weird because of the asterisks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct button is labelled:

> `DHI3A3jZ3R`

Because:

> Removing the italics and whitespace, we get five lines of equal length:
>
> `Hello,ANDandNAND`
> `.HelloAndHiHiYes`
> `soComeGetTheANDg`
> `ateGotTheGateHiH`
> `elloOhANDandAND.`
>
>  By changing all non-capitalized characters to `-`, we get the following:
>
> `H-----AND---NAND`
> `-H----A--H-H-Y--`
> `--C---G--T--AND-`
> `---G--T--G---H-H`
> `----O-AND---AND-`
>
>  This looks like the string `\D$`. If interpreted as a regular expression, `\D` means any non-digit character, and `$` means the end of the line. So, this expression will match any line that does not end with a digit.
>
>  Looking at the button labels, only one label fits this criteria: `DHI3A3jZ3R`.

Comment: This answer is correct! Great job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to work out the message.

I think that

> The word "Hello" (with the 'low' in it) represents 0 or a FALSE value, while "Hi" represents 1 or TRUE.

I don't know yet if

> The italicized parts are meaningful in decoding the message, or if they're used in lieu of quote marks.  I'm leaning toward the former because there are a few things not italicized that aren't quoted words.

If I

> Just read the non-italic parts and count "hello" as 0 (low), "oh" as 0, "Yes" as 1, and "Hi" as 1 (high), I get:
> 0 AND NAND 0 AND 1 1 1 AND 1 0 0 AND AND
> This doesn't make sense to me yet.  I'm not certain that it's right.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: No, you're not.